# How use Blueprint's form styles with password_field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, sass, compass-sass, blueprint-css

I'd like to have my password_fields styled the same as the  Blueprint framework's default style for input fields.  What do I need to put in my .sass for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.

need to append a class to the input in the HAML

```
 = f.password_field :password, :class => 'text'
```

Comment: actually that is only a partial solution.  The other fields still have a different border with 3D shadowing.